# SharedPreferences in FirebaseMessaging Service (Background Service)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, sharedpreferences, background-process

Good Day,

my problem is that the data I get from FCM doesn't get saved in the `SharedPreferences`, if I receive a Notification when the application is closed.

**The Code:**

```
public class SomeService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{

SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

    Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    prefsEditor.putBoolean(Keys.text, Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get("text")));

    prefsEditor.apply();
}

}
```

Comment: Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>(remoteMessage.getData()); and pref = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPref..

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but the problem still remains when the FCM Notification arrives when the application is closed. The values don't get stored in the SharedPreferences :/

Comment: alright, did you check whether data is empty not, what values if getting stored, is your values false ?, and hope you are using data msgs

Answer (score 2):

If you not using FirebaseMessaging Data Message, Firebase didn't call onMessageReceived when on background.
onMessageReceived only called in foreground.

You should use Data Message to make onMessageReceived working in background

this is reference based on [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)
and about message types in firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: Oh, yes I remember that, but why does it start my displayNotification Method that gets called with onMessageReceived (not in the sample post above) ?

Comment: Edit: Ah, Data Message seems to be the solution, I am currently trying it out, could you tell me if Data Message also works with when the application is in the Foreground?

Comment: @Tester3 using non-Data Message, firebase will automatically makes a notification in background, and call onMessageReceived in foreground. if using Data message, firebase will calls onMessageReceived both foreground and background

Comment: That's exactly why I came back I would like to know how you can create data payload with FCM (is it also possible with the console?)

Comment: @Tester3 look this [example](https://gist.github.com/drulabs/c9f6802790c92d74cb7eb2427097899a) . remove "notification" from json, only "data"